# Is there any way to have a chat with a contact on Whatsapp Web (on a computer) not show up on the phone's Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sync

I had this small doubt if it was possible to message contacts and phone numbers, and have the records of those chats only present on Whatsapp Web (not sync with the phone on which Whatsapp is installed). Is this possible?

If I am asking this on the wrong stack exhange, I sincerely apologise. If I am posting this on the wrong place, on which stack exchange should I post this question?

Comment: Whatsapp doesn't offer this as a feature. You might want to email Whatsapp asking this as a feature, though it is unlikely to make an impact on them, but it doesn't hurt either.